# Is it possible to improve efficiency of the function?

Tags: performance-tuning, string-manipulation, parsing, data-types

I have the following function `scriptQ` to check whether an expression is a "script" or not.
This function is frequently called by others, so I need to improve the efficiencies.

```
scriptQ[_] = False;
scriptQ[null|""|"0"] = True;
scriptQ[string_String] :=
    Or[
        DigitQ@string&&!StringStartsQ[string,"0"],
        StringLength@string===1&&LetterQ@string
    ];
scriptQ[symbol_Symbol] :=
    (StringLength@#===1&&LetterQ@#)&@SymbolName@symbol;
scriptQ[natural_Integer] :=
    NonNegative@natural;
```

### Motivation

The motivation is coding/decoding a variable indexed by label and script into/from a single symbol. For example, `"x"<>"dagger"<>"0"` will be coded as `xdagger0` and formatted as $x^{\dagger}_{0}$.

```
_Subsuperscript <=> "variable"<>"label"<>"script" <=> _Symbol
```

In order to tokenize the symbol `xdagger0` as `"x"<>"dagger"<>"0"`,
we need to pre-store the variable $x$ and the label $\dagger$ in some lists, similar to SymPy's `symbols`.

The function `scriptQ` is to check whether an input is a valid "script". The scripts are more broad than variables and labels, and can include single letters and natural numbers:

- multi-letter is excluded since I don't know how to distinguish them from labels;
- negative numbers and strings like e.g. `"0001"` are excluded since it's hard and dirty to convert them between strings and numbers.

### Timing

The test data is as follows:

```
testing[fun_][input_]:=
    Map[
        Association[
            "input"->#,
            "result"->fun[#],
            "type"->Head[#],
            "timing"->(First@RepeatedTiming@fun[#] 1.*^6)
        ]&,
        input
    ]//Dataset;

testing[scriptQ]@{0,10,"","0","10","a",a,null}
testing[scriptQ]@{-1,1/2,1.1," ","00","0a","-1","a1",a1,ab,Null}
```

in which the time unit is $10^{-6}s$.
The timing is rather stable when I repeated run the test. There are some worst cases that the timing is roughly $\sim 10^{-6}$, and others are $\sim 10^{-7}$.

[image]

### Question

- Is it possible to improve the timing to $\sim 10^{-7}$?
- Any suggestions (not related to `scriptQ`) on how to improve efficiency are also welcomed.

Comment: I think your post does not get much attention, because it is lacking some context. IMHO, the best way to improve this is to use  a more uniform data representation to make this type of function obsolete. But maybe you have to write a parser for a stream of data over whose structure you don‘t have any control? You know, people don‘t like to play this type of guessing game.

Comment: Is the set of allowable symbols constrained at all beyond just letters? Like, is it actually just the English alphabet, or do you really need to allow all characters that qualify as letters?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks, I add more explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you could easily enumerate what counts as a letter (e.g. if you can restrict legal letters to the English alphabet), then you can get performance improvement by doing some special case definitions. Also, you can get minor improvement by just reducing the number of boolean operations in general.

```
scriptQ2[_] = False;
scriptQ2[null] = True;
scriptQ2[""] = True;
scriptQ2[" "] = False;
(scriptQ2[#] = True) & /@ ToString /@ Range[0, 9];
(scriptQ2[#] = True) & /@ Flatten[Through[{ToLowerCase, ToUpperCase}[Alphabet[]]]];
(scriptQ2[#] = True) & /@ Symbol /@ Flatten[Through[{ToLowerCase, ToUpperCase}[Alphabet[]]]];
scriptQ2[int_Integer] := NonNegative@int;
scriptQ2[str_String] :=
  Which[
    StringStartsQ[str, "0"], False,
    StringStartsQ[str, "-"], False,
    DigitQ[str], True,
    True, False];
```

Comment: Thanks! Restricting the range of scripts can be a good idea since in most situations I only use English and Greek letters as scripts. I'll test it carefully.